# Seeking Feedback on Mixed-Effects Model with Weighted Observations

Tags: mixed-model, convergence, spearman-rho, weighted-regression, fisher-transform

I've been working on a project where I'm comparing different methods using a mixed-effects model, and I'd appreciate some feedback on my approach.

**Background:**
I have a dataset with several variables:

- `method`: Different methods that are being compared.
- `ref_name`: The reference being used in the benchmarking.
- `val_dataset`: The validation dataset paired with the reference.
- `n_val_samples`: The number of samples in the validation dataset.
- `celltype`: The cell type measured in the dataset.
- `ground_truth`: Proportion values representing the ground truth for the cell type.
- `prediction`: Proportion values representing the predictions.

The primary goal is to assess the performance of different methods based on the Spearman correlation between `ground_truth` and `prediction`.

**What I've Done:**
To account for the variability introduced by `ref_name`, `val_dataset`, and `celltype`, I used a linear mixed-effects model. Here's the R code I used:

```
data %>%
  group_by(method) %>%
  summarise(beta = lme4::lmer(rank(ground_truth) ~ 1 + rank(prediction) + (1|ref_name) + (1|val_dataset) + (1|celltype), weights = n_val_samples)@beta[2])
```

Given the varying number of samples in `val_dataset`, I've used `n_val_samples` as weights, assuming that observations with more samples are more reliable (weights range from 4 to 38).

However, I encountered some warnings related to model convergence when using weights:

```
Caused by warning in `checkConv()`:
! Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00216104 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

Not sure why, using log transformation on weights there are no warnings.

**Seeking Feedback:**

1. Is my approach of using `n_val_samples` as weights justified? Should I consider a transformation for these weights?
2. Are there any potential pitfalls or considerations I might be overlooking in this mixed-effects model setup?
3. Any suggestions on addressing the model convergence issues?

I'd appreciate any insights, comments, or suggestions. Thank you in advance!

**P.S.** I've also contemplated an alternative strategy:

1. Compute the Spearman Rho for each cell type within every dataset.
2. Apply Fisher's transformation to these correlations.
3. Determine the mean/median z-value and subsequently revert it back to a Rho value.
4. For each reference, compute the weighted mean/median, with the weights being the number of samples in each dataset.

Would this approach be more robust or offer any advantages over the mixed-effects model?